# ReactJS component not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component that I want to render if `filteredTodos` is not empty:

```
{filteredTodos.lenght > 0 ? (
  <List 
    todos={todos} 
    setTodos={setTodos}
    filteredTodos={filteredTodos}
  /> 
) : <div className="justify-content-center">No tasks have been added, add a new task</div>}
```

This component tries to renders, only once, and initially the array is empty so my component never renders.

`filteredTodos` changes based on a `useEffect`, and it is updating correctly:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const filterHandler = () => {
        switch(status){
            case "completed": 
                setfilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === true))
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                setfilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === false))
                break;
            default:
                setfilteredTodos(todos);
                break;
        }
    }
    filterHandler();

}, [todos, status]);
```

[image]

Comment: The Classic way to achieve this in React is to use the ``setState`` method:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
  
I had a similar issue, when I changed the code to be class based, and used the ``render()`` it worked as expected.

Comment: Can you show us your `addTodo` handler? Looks like it is mutating the state instead of dispatching a new instance.

Comment: filteredTodos.length is misspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.
Please check the comment I left you regarding showing the `addTodo`. Looks like the issue could be there.

Regarding the code, some side comments:

### Avoid Typos

You can use a linter to help you out with this. `length` is misspelled here:

```
{filteredTodos.lenght > 0 ? (
```

### Unique IDS should be unique.

Avoid using random numbers for ids. Despite being highly unlikely, random numbers could eventually be the same. Try to move to a library like `uuid`.

### Readability counts.

```
setfilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === false)
```

could be:

```
setfilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed) //or
setfilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
```